# Using key_press_event to select a 'mode' for different types of pick_event

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

I've been struggling to create an interactive plot picker where I have 3 different pick_events.  These pick_events have a calculation in each.  I would like to press '1', '2', or '3' and it will be a mode for that corresponding pick_event and I would like it to stay in that mode until another mode is pressed.  So far I've tried this code, but I'm inexperienced with OOP and trying to learn.

```
class MyClick(object):
    def __init__(self):

    def pick(self, event):
        artist = event.artist
        xmouse, ymouse = event.mouseevent.xdata, event.mouseevent.ydata
        self.x, self.y = np.array(artist.get_xdata()),np.array(artist.get_ydata())
        self.ind = event.ind
        #self.maxind = self.y[self.ind].argsort()[-1:] #[::-1]
        #axes.plot(x[ind[self.maxind]],y[ind[self.maxind]],'*')
        #figure.canvas.draw()

    def press(self, event):
        sys.stdout.flush()
        if event.key == '1':
            # peak
            self.maxind = self.y[self.ind].argsort()[-1:] #[::-1]
            print(y[ind[self.maxind]])
        elif event.key == '2':
            # onset
            print('onset')
        elif event.key == '3':
            # offset
            print('offset')
        else:
            print('wrong key press')

if __name__ == "__main__":
    figure = plt.figure()
    axes = figure.add_subplot(1, 1, 1)
    data_plot, = axes.plot(Frame, R_Fz_dn_bc , picker=5) #plot data
    axes.autoscale(tight=True)

    browser = MyClick()
    cid = figure.canvas.mpl_connect('pick_event', browser.pick)
    cid = figure.canvas.mpl_connect('key_press_event', browser.press)

    plt.show()
```

I've omitted some code that doesn't deal with this.  I've tried making 3 different picker functions but also tried to make one picker function and the calculation in each key press event function.  Any help would be a huge appreciation.  I've been struggling with this for weeks.  I'm also looking for a way to have the points picked in a numpy array so I can do other calculations later.

Thanks!

PS: I apologize if there is a previous topic on this. I haven't found anything so if there is point me there!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `press()` method to record the last key pressed as an attribute of the `MyClick` instance, then in the `pick()` method check which mode is currently active and do whatever calculation is appropriate:

```
class MyClick(object):

    def __init__(self):

        # initialize mode
        self._mode = 1

    def pick(self, event):
        """do some calculation depending on the last key pressed"""

        if self._mode == 1:
            # do something...
            pass

        elif self._mode == 2:
            # do something different...
            pass

        elif self._mode == 3:
            # do something else entirely...
            pass

    def press(self, event):
        """record last key pressed"""

        if event.key == '1':
            self._mode = 1

        elif event.key == '2':
            self._mode = 2

        elif event.key == '3':
            self._mode = 3
```

Comment: This is exactly what I have been trying to accomplish!  Thank you so much for the help!

Comment: After successfully implementing this into my code correctly I've ran into a small and weird problem that may be a bug?  As soon as I press '2' or '3' I'm not able to use the GUI zoom button or grab functions.  No errors or anything.  Still works if I press '1'.  Any ideas? @ali_m

Comment: I would need to see what exactly you're doing in your `pick` method. You should ask a separate question and post some runnable example code that reproduces the problem.

Comment: I will work on it a little more see if I can fix the problem before creating another post.  So far I am OK with having zoom and pan functionality only after pressing '1' mode.  It doesn't seem like anything with my code in the `pick` method after doing some tests.  Thanks for the help and the suggestions! @ali_m